# Find the minimum Adversary's Advantage

Tags: mac

I am wondering how to solve the problem below:

Suppose we have a $MAC$ scheme $I=(S,V)$. There is another algorithm that can find a pair of texts $(m0,m1)$, with $m0≠m1$ such that $S(k,m0)=S(k,m1)$ for $1/10$ of the Keys $K$.What is the minimum $Adv$<sub>$MAC$</sub>$[A,I]$ for every adversary $A$?

MAC defined over $(K,M,T)$ is a pair of efficient algorithms $(S,V)$:

- $S(k,m):$ returns a message athentication code $t$ which belongs to a set $T$
- $V(k,m,t):$ returns a value $true$ or $false$ depending on the correctness of the received authentication code

$M$ is a set of all possible messages $m$
$K$ is a set of all possible keys $k$
$T$ is a set of all possible authentication codes $t$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use proper formatting and define your notation. (And since this is obviously homework, please also tell us what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.)

Comment: What is "(S,V)MAC"? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: I suspect it just means that they're representing their MAC scheme as a pair of functions $S$ and $V$, which probably stand for "signer" and "verifier". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code#Definitions) uses a similar notation. But yeah, the question should really mention that, or at least link to a definition.

Comment: @stathisb: ...where you've now introduced three new undefined symbols ($K$, $M$ and $T$). I can *guess* what those mean (I bet they're the keyspace, message space and tag space respectively), but such notation isn't really unambiguous or universal enough that you could just assume that everybody will understand it (they way in math you can *usually* assume e.g. that $\pi \approx 3.14159265$), especially if they learned crypto from a different textbook than yours. But anyway, more important than all this notation is really that you still haven't told us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think I defined everything now... My problem is that even if I've read everything about the theoritical scheme of MAC, I'm still unable to find a way to calculate the Advantage.

Comment: @stathisb: Are you missing the *definition* of advantage for MAC schemes, or the way to obtain a non-negligible advantage for this particular question (or something else)? If the former, your textbook (or lecture notes) *should* have it, assuming that it's using the term "advantage" for MACs in the first place; if the latter, see my answer below.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I just came up with the idea that the Adversary's Advantage of this problem must be the propability of finding the key $k$ of  the subset $1/10$ of $K$. So the $Adv$$MAC$$[A,I]$=1/k / 1/10$. Because we know that the Adversary can generate two different messages that give the same valid tag and that applies only for 1/10 of the number of the possible keys, I came to the above conclusion. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer to the question, as literally asked, is $0$.  This is because you're asking for the minimum advantage "for every adversary", and the set of possible adversaries includes e.g. the trivial adversary that simply always outputs an empty message and a random tag $t \in T$, and thus has a probability of exactly $1/|T|$ of successful forgery.

However, that's almost certainly not what the question is *trying* to ask, if only because the answer above doesn't actually make any use of the extra collision-finding algorithm.  What I suspect the question *should* ask is something like:

> Let $(S,V)$ be a MAC scheme (as defined above), and let $C$ be an efficient algorithm that will output a pair of distinct messages $m_1 \ne m_2$ such that $S(k, m_1) = S(k, m_2)$ for a randomly chosen key $k \in K$ with probability $1/10$.  Show that for any such triple $(S,V,C)$ there exists an adversary $A$ (with oracle access to $S(k,\cdot)$ and $C$) that can forge a message with advantage at least $a > 0$ independently of the security parameter, and determine the maximum value of $a$ for which this claim holds (assuming that secure MAC schemes exist).

As for solving this problem, consider an adversary $A$ that uses $C$ to generate a message pair $m_1, m_2$, queries the oracle for $t_1 = S(k,m_1)$ and outputs $(m_2, t_1)$.  What is the advantage of such an adversary?

For bonus points, show that, given a secure MAC scheme $(S^*,V^*)$ (i.e. one against which no adversary has more than a negligible advantage), we can construct a triple of efficient algorithms $(S,V,C)$ that has the property described in the question, and against which no adversary can have more than a negligibly higher advantage than the adversary $A$ described in the previous paragraph.